# insert a symbol above a letter

Tags: equations, symbols, accents

How do I draw a curve accent over a letter in math mode, as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `yhmath` package defines an extensible `\wideparen` math accent:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \wideparen{\mathbf{j}}\neq \wideparen{\wideparen{\mathbf{j}_e }}\neq \wideparen{\wideparen{\mathbf{j}_{e ,f}}}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use `accents`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\frownaccent}[1]{\accentset{\frown}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\frownaccent{\mathbf{j}}\ne\frownaccent{\frownaccent{\mathbf{j}}}_{e}$

\end{document}
```

[image]